# LINQ query with Timestamp column comparison in NHibernate

Tags: linq, postgresql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using automapping with Fluent NHibernate, and have used the following code to ensure that NHibernate does not strip away the milliseconds:

```
public class TimestampTypeConvention : IPropertyConvention, IPropertyConventionAcceptance
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.Type == typeof(DateTime) || x.Type == typeof(DateTimeOffset));
    }

    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.CustomType<TimestampType>();
    }
}
```

This works quite well, so the data is stored correctly in the database.

However, when I run the following LINQ query, I don't get a match where I would expect it:

```
bool isDuplicate = session.Query<TagData>()
                          .Any(x => x.TagName == message.EventTag.TagName
                               && x.TimeStamp == message.EventTag.TimeStamp.UtcDateTime);
```

The resulting SQL looks like this, and explains why this doesn't work:

```
select tagdata0_."Id" as column1_0_, tagdata0_."TagName" as column2_0_,
tagdata0_."TimeStamp" as column3_0_, tagdata0_."Value" as column4_0_,
tagdata0_."QualityTimeStamp" as column5_0_, tagdata0_."QualitySubstatus" as column6_0_,
tagdata0_."QualityExtendedSubstatus" as column7_0_, tagdata0_."QualityLimit" as column8_0_,
tagdata0_."QualityDataSourceError" as column9_0_, tagdata0_."QualityTagStatus" as column10_0_,
tagdata0_."TagType" as column11_0_ from "TagData" tagdata0_
where tagdata0_."TagName"=:p0 and tagdata0_."TimeStamp"=:p1 limit 1;
:p0 = 'VALVE_HW_CMD' [Type: String (0)],
:p1 = 01.03.2013 16:51:30 [Type: DateTime (0)]
```

How can I force the generated query to use the full precision?

BTW, `message.EventTag.TimeStamp` is a `DateTimeOffset`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was fooled by the logging output: The actual SQL (taken from the PostgreSQL log file) looks like this:

```
SELECT this_."Id" as column1_0_0_, this_."TagName" as column2_0_0_,
this_."TimeStamp" as column3_0_0_, this_."Value" as column4_0_0_,
this_."QualityTimeStamp" as column5_0_0_, this_."QualitySubstatus" as column6_0_0_,
this_."QualityExtendedSubstatus" as column7_0_0_, this_."QualityLimit" as column8_0_0_,
this_."QualityDataSourceError" as column9_0_0_, this_."QualityTagStatus" as column10_0_0_,
this_."TagType" as column11_0_0_ FROM "TagData" this_
WHERE this_."TimeStamp" = ((E'2013-03-01 16:51:30.509498')::timestamp)
```

That's the real reason that it didn't work quite as expected: The `timestamp` column in PostgreSQL only has microsecond accuracy, whereas the `DateTimeDiff` here has the value of 16:51:30.5094984, which means 1/10th of a microsecond accuracy. The only way to preserve the full accuracy seems to be to store the ticks in the database.

(Another reason for my confusion was that I received the duplicate messages from MassTransit more or less simultaneously on different threads, so checking the DB for duplicates of course didn't always work. O, the wonders of multithreading!)